# An inequality in Huisken paper

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis

I am reading a paper is written by Gerhard Huisken 'Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into sphere' and I want to show  the following statement

Let $p\ge 2$ then for $\eta>0$ and any $0\le \sigma \le \frac{1}{2}$, $\alpha=2-\sigma$ we have the estimate $$n\epsilon^2\int f^p_\sigma H^2 d\mu\le (2\eta p+5)\int \dfrac{1}{H^\alpha}f^{p-1}_\sigma |\nabla H|^2d\mu+\eta^{-1}(p-1)\int f^{p-2}_{\sigma}|\nabla f_{\sigma}|^2 d\mu$$

So in the proof, by considering the Laplacian and so on with this inequality $$ \int \frac{1}{H^\alpha}f^{p-1}_\sigma Zd\mu\le 4\int\frac{1}{H}f^{p-1}_{\sigma}\langle\nabla_i f_\sigma,\nabla_i H\rangle d\mu+\dfrac{n-1}{n}\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-1}_\sigma|\nabla H|^2 d\mu+(p-1)\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-2}_\sigma\langle h^{\circ}_{ij},\nabla_i H\cdot\nabla_j H\rangle d\mu+\alpha\int \dfrac{1}{H^2}f^{p}_\sigma|\nabla H|^2 d\mu$$

Given $0\le f_{\sigma}\le H^\sigma, |h^\circ_{ij}|^2=f_{\sigma}H^{\alpha}$

So far my effort is $$\dfrac{n-1}{n}\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-1}_\sigma|\nabla H|^2 d\mu+\alpha\int \dfrac{1}{H^2}f^{p}_\sigma|\nabla H|^2 d\mu\le 3\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-1}_\sigma|\nabla H|^2 d\mu$$ and\begin{align}
(p-1)\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-2}_\sigma\langle h^{\circ}_{ij},\nabla_i H\cdot\nabla_j f_{\sigma}\rangle d\mu&\le(p-1)\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-2}_\sigma\langle h^{\circ}_{ij},\nabla_i H\cdot\nabla_j f_{\sigma}\rangle d\mu\\
&\le(p-1)\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-2}_\sigma| h^{\circ}_{ij}| |\nabla H| |\nabla f_{\sigma}| d\mu\\
&=(p-1)\int \dfrac{2}{H^\alpha}f^{p-2}_\sigma(\sqrt{f_{\sigma}}|\nabla H|) (\sqrt{H^\alpha} |\nabla f_{\sigma}|) d\mu
\end{align}Then follow by Young's inequality, can get the form of the linear combination of $$ \int \dfrac{1}{H^\alpha}f^{p-1}_\sigma |\nabla H|^2d\mu,\int f^{p-2}_{\sigma}|\nabla f_{\sigma}|^2 d\mu$$ My problem is I cant bound the remaining part by the linear combination above $$4\int\frac{1}{H}f^{p-1}_{\sigma}\langle\nabla_i f_\sigma,\nabla_i H\rangle d\mu\le4\int\frac{1}{H}f^{p-1}_{\sigma}|\nabla f_\sigma| |\nabla H| d\mu$$ All the relevant defintion, $h_{ij}$ is the second fundamental form and $g_{ij}$ is the first fundamental form. Then $H=g^{ij}h_{ij}$ and $$f_{\sigma}=\dfrac{|A|^2-H^2/n}{H^{2-\sigma}}\Longrightarrow f_{\sigma}H^{\alpha}=|A|^2-H^2/n=:|h^{\circ}_{ij}|^2$$

Comment: Please include all relevant definitions. In particular, are there any relation between $f_\sigma$ and $H$?

Comment: @WillieWong Sure I has made some edit above, thank you.